# Вопрос по управлению

Tags: морфология

Почему же употреблена форма "кукол" ?
**Кукол я не любила с детства.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Слово "кукла" в русском языке считается одушевленным. Поэтому все абсолютно правильно: во множественном числе у одушевленных существительных форма винительного падежа совпадает с формой родительного (у неодушевленных - форма винительного падежа совпадает с формой именительного падежа, сравните: ***игры** я не любила с детства*).

Answer (score 0):

> Я не любила с детства (*кого?*) [кукол](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0).

А какую форму Вы бы туда подставили?

Comment: Нет, я-то согласен, но что-то вот забыл, от чего зависит выбор формы :)